# Writing html file to new file but modified in batch

Tags: batch-file

What I'm trying to do is make a batch file to get the embed html for youtube, modify it, then make a new file with the modified html in it. I think the problem is the echo %code%>Video.html because it wasnt writing correctly and the <> tags in the html were interfering.  I have tried all sorts of things, and none of them work.

Here's my code so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
title Youtube Player 1.0

REM USER CODE ENTRY
echo Enter the video code (The code from the video url)
set /p vidcode=
cls
echo Getting video code...
REM REPLACEMENT
set replace=%vidcode%
set /p code= <apicode.txt
call set code=%%code:iAX-81REC0k=%replace%%%
cls
echo %code%
pause
echo Generating HTML File...
echo %code%>Video.html
pause
cls
echo Opening File...
start Video.html
cls
```

If anyone can help that would be great

Answer (score 0):

`^` is an escape character in batch code that is used to escape certain poison characters like `<` and `>`

Here's  a sample:

```
>video.html echo(^<tag^>
```

Comment: I tried that and it now says "System cannot find the file specified" when it tries to echo the %code% variable.

Comment: Your problem is that you are manipulating the variable and then escaping changes from a simple case where it can be escaped as I have shown.  If you edit your question to include actual example data and show what needs to be done, then you may get better suggestion.